Incomplete Attribute Retrieval
I'm trying to extract element types and their attributes from a Google Doc using Google Apps Script.(to create a html with atributes to send with email) I've created a recursive function to traverse the document structure and log the found elements and their attributes.
However, I'm encountering two issues:
Incomplete attribute retrieval: Not all attributes are being captured. For instance, DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR is missing from the output.
I've tried [mention any troubleshooting steps you've taken, such as checking documentation, experimenting with different element types, etc.].
Example:
google docs countain: This is an essay
The result is:
Infos   Used Elements and Attributes: 

Rang: 0
,Type: BODY_SECTION    ,
Text: 
,attributes:  ,STRIKETHROUGH: null
,BACKGROUND_COLOR: null
,PAGE_HEIGHT: 841.68
,MARGIN_LEFT: 72
,FONT_SIZE: null
,UNDERLINE: null
,PAGE_WIDTH: 595.4399999999999
,MARGIN_RIGHT: 72
,MARGIN_TOP: 72
,BOLD: null
,LINK_URL: null
,MARGIN_BOTTOM: 72
,FOREGROUND_COLOR: null
,FONT_FAMILY: null
,ITALIC: null
,

Rang: 1
,Type: PARAGRAPH    ,
Text: This is an essay
,attributes:  ,UNDERLINE: null
,SPACING_BEFORE: null
,FONT_FAMILY: null
,BACKGROUND_COLOR: null
,ITALIC: null
,BOLD: null
,SPACING_AFTER: null
,INDENT_END: null
,LINK_URL: null
,HEADING: NORMAL
,FONT_SIZE: null
,STRIKETHROUGH: null
,LINE_SPACING: null
,LEFT_TO_RIGHT: true
,INDENT_FIRST_LINE: null
,INDENT_START: null
,HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT: null
,FOREGROUND_COLOR: null
,

Rang: 2
,Type: TEXT    ,
Text: This is an essay
,attributes:  ,FONT_SIZE: null
,STRIKETHROUGH: null
,BOLD: null
,LINK_URL: null
,BACKGROUND_COLOR: null
,FONT_FAMILY: null
,ITALIC: null
,FOREGROUND_COLOR: null
,UNDERLINE: null

I'm looking for guidance on:
How to ensure all attributes are captured for each element.
How to accurately represent dynamic text changes within elements.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
function listUsedElementTypesAndAttributes() {
  // Open google doc by Id
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1Wq2GOkswbDMKfdqCweV9WxlNyGBStXkx29GGU1A8Saw');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  // Initialize the list to store the element types and attributes used
  var usedElementsAndAttributes = [];
    
  // Function to check and add element types and attributes
  function checkElementAndAttributes(element,rang) {
    usedElementsAndAttributes.push("\n\nRang: "+rang + "\n");    
    var type = element.getType();
    usedElementsAndAttributes.push("Type: "+type + "    ");

    var text ="";    
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT || type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH || type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM || type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_CEL  ){
      text = element.getText();
    }  
    usedElementsAndAttributes.push("\nText: "+text+"\n")

    var attributes = element.getAttributes();
    usedElementsAndAttributes.push('attributes:  ');
    for (var attr in attributes) {
      usedElementsAndAttributes.push(attr + ": " + attributes[attr]+"\n")
    }
  }
  
  //      Recursive function
  // Parcourir tous les éléments du document
  function traverseElements(element,rang) {
    checkElementAndAttributes(element,rang);
    
    if (element.getNumChildren) {
      var numChildren = element.getNumChildren();
      for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
        traverseElements(element.getChild(i),rang + 1)
      }
    }
    else { rang = rang-1 }
  }
  //      End of recursive function

var rang = 0
  traverseElements(body,rang);
  
  // Show list
  Logger.log('Used Elements and Attributes: ' + usedElementsAndAttributes);
}


In the Documents Service (Class DocumentApp), the methods that return style attributes might not include the properties that have not set a value by the user. Hence, they inherit the definition from the parent element or use the default value.
A text element belonging to a paragraph using the default Normal style might not return the attribute for the background color. In this case, look at the body attributes.
Example
function bodyAttributes(){
  const attributes = DocumentApp
     .getActiveDocument()
     .getBody()
     .getAttributes();
  Logger.log(attributes)
}












Info
{MARGIN_BOTTOM=72.0, FONT_FAMILY=null, PAGE_WIDTH=612.0, LINK_URL=null, FONT_SIZE=null, MARGIN_LEFT=72.0, ITALIC=null, BACKGROUND_COLOR=#ffffff, BOLD=null, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null, MARGIN_RIGHT=72.0, MARGIN_TOP=72.0, PAGE_HEIGHT=792.0, UNDERLINE=null, STRIKETHROUGH=null}



Please note that the value for the attribute BACKGROUND_COLOR is #ffffff
